# UITableView - Insert rows with a custom cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to insert a cell into a table when the last item has been deleted. Currently I'm using the code below, however it inserts the wrong cell. How do I insert a row and choose the kind by identifier?

```
table?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: Please Include the code for `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

The table view will call you back to configure the new cells. It's in there that you specify what kind of cell goes at what index. That's done in `tableView:cellForRowAt:`.